# rotating around point turns into spiral

Tags: java, rotation, spiral

I am engineering some program that simulates a steel wire rope for my bachelor thesis. But while trying to make a point (centre of a strand (midden) rotating about the centre of the cable(middencable), the point are not rotating, but are in a spiral shape: converting to the centre of the cable.

My code is this:

```
z =  Math.toRadians( z);
        double xpoint = super.midden.getX(); //original point
        double ypoint = super.midden.getY(); //original point
        double cCableX = super.middenCable.getX();
        double cCableY = super.middenCable.getY(); 
        double dx = xpoint - cCableX;
        double dy = ypoint - cCableY;
        double cosangle = Math.cos(z);
        double sinangle = Math.sin(z);

        double x1 = cCableX + cosangle * dx - sinangle * dy;
        double y1 = cCableY + sinangle * dx - cosangle * dy;


        super.midden.setX(x1);
        super.midden.setY(y1);
```

anyone an idea how it making a circle, and not converting to the centre i am trying to rotate around?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

your recalculation of midden points seems to be flawed; assuming `z` is the delta angle:

```
double curangle = Math.atan2(dx, dy);
double dist     = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
double x1 = cCableX + dist * Math.cos(curangle+z);
double y1 = cCableY + dist * Math.sin(curangle+z);
```

this code is poc. it most probably has a poor performance and it is not checked for numerical stability.